# ERROR: could not find gem locally or in a repository

Tags: maven, maven-2, rubygems, jruby

I mavenizing my project and found that some gems can't be installed from maven.
When I run

> gem install jruby-openssl -v 0.7.2

from command line I get following output:

> Successfully installed jruby-openssl-0.7.2

When I run maven I get an error:

> ERROR:  could not find gem jruby-openssl locally or in a repository

There is my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
        <artifactId>jruby-complete</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
...

<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${exec.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>install-gems</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>org.jruby.Main</mainClass>
            <arguments>
                <argument>-S</argument>
                <argument>gem</argument>
                <argument>install</argument>
                <argument>jruby-openssl</argument>
                <argument>-v</argument>
                <argument>0.7.2</argument>
                <arguments>rails</arguments>
                <arguments>-v</arguments>
                <arguments>2.3.8</arguments>
                <arguments>rcov</arguments>
                <arguments>-v</arguments>
                <arguments>0.9.11</arguments>
                <arguments>activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter</arguments>
                <arguments>-v</arguments>
                <arguments>1.2.1</arguments>
                <arguments>will_paginate</arguments>
                <arguments>-v</arguments>
                <arguments>2.3.15</arguments>
                <arguments>validates_timeliness</arguments>
                <arguments>-v</arguments>
                <arguments>2.3.2</arguments>
                <argument>--no-rdoc</argument>
                <argument>--no-test</argument>
                <argument>--user-install</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

I can't install only some gems like open-ssl, rcov, will_paginate, activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter.

Did anyone have the similar issue?

I use jruby 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

To install a jruby gem use.

```
jruby -S gem install jruby-openssl -v 0.7.2
```

See of this helps.